# How to write from input form to text file in PhoneGap

Tags: javascript, cordova

So my employer has assigned me to create a cross-platform prototype application using PhoneGap. The problem is that I do not have a strong web development background outside of HTML and CSS-- I do not know Javascript at all really. I have a strong background in both static and dynamically linked object oriented languages-- Java, C++, and Python but the syntax of Javascript is really throwing me off as I walk through these PhoneGap tutorials.

Right now I am trying to understand how to pass an argument to a write-to-file function that will be called when I click a button. Here is the relevant chain of methods that I need to follow to be able to write to a file:

```
    function onDeviceReady() {
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFSSuccess, onFSError);
    }

    function onFSSuccess(fileSystem) {
        console.log("checkpoint 1");
        console.log("Opened file system: " + fileSystem.name);
        fileSystem.root.getFile("testingoutput.txt", {create:true, exclusive:false}, gotFileEntry, onFSError);
    }

    function gotFileEntry(fileEntry) {
        console.log("checkpoint 2");
        fileEntry.createWriter(gotFileWriter, onFSError);
    }
    function gotFileWriter(writer) {
        console.log("checkpoint 3");
        writer.onwriteend = function() {
            console.log("write has ended!");
        };
        writer.seek(writer.length);
        writer.write("test test test");
        console.log(writer.length);
    }
    function onFSError(err) {
        console.log("in onFSError");
        console.log(err.code);
    }
```

I get the idea of what is going on here and the dependence that one object has on another object if I am going to be able to write to a file, but I am confused about this portion of the code:

```
        window.requestFileSystem(LocalFileSystem.PERSISTENT, 0, onFSSuccess, onFSError);
```

If I have to pass an argument (user input from a form) to the on FSSuccess function-- so that it can ultimately be sent along to the gotFileWriter() to be written-- how do I also pass the needed fileSystem object argument to onFSSuccess? In the above line it looks like it is passed implicitly. Is there a self. or this. identifier that I can call to pass the created fileSystem object to onFSSuccess()?

Comment: The fileSystem is passed implicitly. What you could do is don't request the file system until you have the user input in hand and then just replace the "test test test" with the text field value or whatever. Or your could save the writer (from in gotFileWriter) reference to a higher scope and call the write method once you have the user input.